# Impact velocity of falling rod about pivot point

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

A thin uniform rod of mass M and length L is
positioned vertically above an anchored frictionless
pivot point, as shown above, and then allowed to
fall to the ground. With what speed does the free
end of the rod strike the ground?

This is from the physics GRE (2001) and I wasn't quite sure how to solve it. I tried $E = mgL = \frac{1}{2}I\omega^{2} $ and used the moment of inertia about the end of a rod $I = \frac{1}{3}MR^{2}$ because the linear translational energy drops out but in order to get the right answer apparently I needed $E = mg\frac{L}{2}$ Why would potential energy be $mg\frac{L}{2}$ if I'm taking the it around the pivot point (a distance L away from the other end of the rod)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Change in PE depends on vertical distance through which the centre of mass falls.

Comment: Why the negative votes ? The OP obviously tried to solve the problem, compared with the correct solution and even correctly identified his error. He asks a physical explanation of the correct formula for the potentila enenrgy, which is obviously on topic for me.

Comment: Any reason why this isn't simply a v = sq(2gd)?

Comment: @YogiDMT:  that doesn't work because there's rotational kinetic energy as well as translational.

Comment: Ah yes, i misread his post as just a rod being dropped from a pivot. OP needs to include more information then to get the answer he wants.

Comment: It's a GRE question. I can't include anymore information

Comment: To me, the post contains all information needed, including the attempted resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial potential energy is indeed $mgL/2$. Your wrong use of $mgL$ would correspond to the case where all the mass of the rod would be concentrated at height $L$ (and, of course, it would also change $I$). Here the mass of the rod is spread between $z=0$ and $z=L$. The sum of all these contributions corresponds is the same as the one where the mass is concentrated at the center of mass is (per definition of the center of mass). Since the rod is uniform, the center of mass $G$ is at its center, at initially altitude $z_G=L/2$